# What is the right way to syntax writing in list(map)?

Tags: python

The goal is to have a list[1:11] that has x-2 to every number less than 5.

```
lst = list[1,11]
lst
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

That's what I'm working with. Tried:

```
list(map(lambda x: x-2 for x<5 in lst, lst))
list(map(x-2, filter(lambda x: x<5 in lst))
list(if x < 5 in lst(map(lambda x: x-2)))
```

I'm very new to Python syntax. What I tried above and many others similar to these result in SyntaxError. Sorry if I made mistakes while describing my problem since I'm also new to Stack.

Comment: You may want to check [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) -- usage : `list( range(1, 11) )`

Comment: thank you! I never noticed this mistake when posting the question. I used range in my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution would be:

```py
solution = list(map(lambda x: x-2 if x < 5 else x, lst))
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know "else" was necessary for this to work. I thought anything not fitting to if would stay same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
result = list(map(lambda x: x-2 if x<5 else x, lst))
```

Here is another possible solution:

```
result = list(map(lambda x: x-2*(x<5), lst))
```

Here is your desired output (with `lst = list(range(1, 11))`):

```
>>> result
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```